# Dativ oder Akkusativ für 'beibringen'?

Tags: dative, accusative

Ich habe eine Frage nach dem Gebrauch des Verbs 'beibringen'.

Im Wörterbuch steht: jemandem(dat) etwas(akk) beibringen

Ich habe aber [einen Artikel](http://www.dw.com/de/die-neuen-deutschen-helden-sind-anders/a-15424663) gefunden, wo jemanden(akk) verwendet wird, anstatt Dativ.

> Die Zeitung belohnt seit 2005 mit ihrem alljährlichen Panterpreis "Helden des Alltags", zum Beispiel eine pensionierte Lehrerin, **die Analphabeten** das Schreiben beibringt...
>   (aus Top Thema, Deutsch Welle)

Ist das nur ein Fehler oder erlaubter Gebrauch? Ich bin nicht sicher, weil es auch ein ähnliches Verb gibt, das Akkusativ nehmen, z. B. 'lehren'.

---

I've got a question about usage of the verb 'beibringen'
Dictionary has it that it takes the form of:
someone(dative) + something(accusative) + beibringen,

But I've also found an article where someone was accusative instead of dative, in Top Thema from Deutsch Welle
Is this an allowed usage, or merely a mistake? Not sure, because there is also similar verb that does take accusative, such as 'lehren'

Comment: I think, your misconception is the "die"? Here it refers to the "Lehrerin".

Comment: IQV is right, you could write *die den/einigen/vielen Analphabeten das Schreiben beibringt*, which makes clear, that *Analphabeten* is the dative object.

Comment: @IQV, guidot, Christophe/ Vielen Dank, Das war mein Fehler. Nun ist is alles klar.

Answer (score 11):

Was im Wörterbuch steht entspricht hier den normalen Regeln der deutschen Sprache: jemandem (Dativ/Dativobjekt) etwas (Akkusative/Akkustivobjekt) beibringen.

Man muss den Satz aber richtig verstehen: "(...) eine pensionierte Lehrerin, die Analphabeten das Schreiben beibringt (...).": "die" ist hier kein Artikel zum (Dativobjekt) "Analphabeten", sondern ein [Relativpronomen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativpronomen), das auf "Lehrerin" zurückverweist. Der Satz folgt also den normalen grammatikalischen Regeln.